# Error when trying to make generic method in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, repository

This is my code Service interface (which i am trying to generify):

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public interface Service<T extends Planning>  {

    List<T> get(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort);

    //PagingResponse getOther(Specification<T> spec, HttpHeaders headers, Sort sort);

}
```

And I created another class that extends to Service class, here are my PlanningServiceImpl class :

```
@Data
@Service
public class PlanningServiceImpl implements PlanningService, com.qoze.meeting.services.Service<Planning> {

    @Autowired
    private PlanningRepositoryInterface planningRepository;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Planning> getAllPlannings() {
        return planningRepository.findAll();
    }
   
    @Override
    public List<Planning> get(Specification<Planning> spec, Sort sort){
        return planningRepository.findAll(spec, sort);
    }

}
```

My PlanningService interface :

```
public interface PlanningService{

    Iterable<Planning> getAllPlannings();
}
```

First the compiler doesn't recognize the spec parameter given in parameter. Then I change to put the extends on T object.

But here with my service I only allowed to work with Planning objects, I wanted at the beginning to have a generic Service and use several objects. Can someone help to have a generic service in spring boot app?

Comment: it tells me to create findAll method in my repository

Comment: What does `PlanningRepositoryInterface` extend?

Comment: It's this : `public interface PlanningRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<Planning, Integer>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Planning, Integer>`

Comment: You have to extend [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) for that method to be available.

Comment: Yes i `forget i already extend JpaSpecificationExecutor<Planning>`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i updated my question can you check please ?

Comment: Okay i updated the original question my bad ^^ @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Could you provide details for the following questions or update the main question by following  details?
- what do you have right now in code?
- what is the error or problem?
- what do you want to get?

Comment: First i had an error but not anymore, but i wanted to have a generic Service to use several objects as i said in the question. But here i am only allowed to use this Service with the Planning object due to `T extends Planning`. I wanted to have a generic service because i have code duplication, so i created this Service interface.